# Ansible job prompting for password

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible job that ensures certain directories are present on remote servers and then copies files into them.

```
---
- hosts: cac
  tasks: 
   - name: Create Required directories.
     file: path=/opt/app/ca/{{ item }} state=directory mode=0755 owner=admin group=admin
     with_items:
     - cac/webapps
     - cac/iam_config

   - name: Copy and unarchive webapps node.
     synchronize: src=/home/ansible/templates/app/Sprint6/webapps dest=/opt/app/ca/iam_cac checksum=yes
```

My environmnet file is:

```
[cac]
10.169.99.70
10.169.99.72
[cac:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=admin
ansible_ssh_pass=xyz
```

When I run the job, in debug mode I can see that Task one is run as admin user and no password is prompted from me.

But the second task asks me for the admin password.

```
TASK [Copy and unarchive webapps node.] ****************************************
task path: /home/ansible/playbooks/release-deploy.yaml:10
<10.169.99.70> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<10.169.99.70> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-93847262523946 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-93847262523946="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-93847262523946 `" ) && sleep 0'
<10.169.99.72> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<10.169.99.72> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-27220657560306 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-27220657560306="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-27220657560306 `" ) && sleep 0'
<10.169.99.70> PUT /tmp/tmpBP7rLm TO /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-93847262523946/synchronize
<10.169.99.72> PUT /tmp/tmpVKR5A9 TO /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-27220657560306/synchronize
<10.169.99.70> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-93847262523946/synchronize; rm -rf "/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-93847262523946/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
<10.169.99.72> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-27220657560306/synchronize; rm -rf "/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477753023.09-27220657560306/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
admin@10.169.99.72's password: admin@10.169.99.70's password:
```

I am confused as to why this step is requiring me to enter the password when I have configured it in my environment file.

Secondly why does it say?

```
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence in the [`synchronize` module doc page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) answers your second question (why does it say `ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible:`?

> `synchronize` is a wrapper around the rsync command, meant to make common tasks with rsync easier. It is run and originates on the local host where Ansible is being run.

As for the first question, the parameters section in the same manual explains you need to use the following argument:

> `use_ssh_args`
>   (default: `no`)
>   Use the ssh_args specified in ansible.cfg.

While it refers only to `ansible.cfg`, it refers to the variables defined in the inventory file as well.